# Text generation with deep neural network?

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, generative-models, sequence, text-generation

For my master's project, I have to build a deep learning model for text generation: the model learns on a set of sentences, then it generates new sentences based on those from which it learned.
I wonder which model should I use? Which model can generate new text without giving it input text?

Comment: Searching for "text generation models" would be a good start. Part of the point of a master's project is showing you can do a literature review. I'd save using StackExchange sites for more specific questions, about things you didn't understand in a particular paper, etc.